# JUnit java.lang.AssertionError: Unimplemented

Tags: java, junit, jdeveloper, junit-runner

i have a java class tested with JUnit but aI am getting a java.lang.AssertionError: Unimplemented

for all these Methods  and i can't find the error

exemple:
java.lang.AssertionError: Unimplemented     demo.model.KiwiantraagstellerTest.testRemoveKiwikinder(KiwiantraagstellerTest.java:262)

java.lang.AssertionError: Unimplemented
     demo.model.KiwiantraagstellerTest.testSetAnschrift(KiwiantraagstellerTest.java:30)

...
please help me

My class:

```
package demo.model;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import org.junit.Assert;
@Entity
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Kiwiantraagsteller.findAll", query = "select o from Kiwiantraagsteller o") })
@SequenceGenerator(name = "Kiwiantraagsteller_Id_Seq_Gen", sequenceName = "KIWIANTRAAGSTELLER_ID_SEQ_GEN",
                   allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
public class Kiwiantraagsteller implements Serializable { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4262686236921972336L;
    private String anschrift;
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Kiwiantraagsteller_Id_Seq_Gen")
    private Integer antragstelerid;
    private String bic;
    private String familienstand;
    private String geburtsname;
    private String geschlecht;
    private String iban;
    private String kontoinhaber;
    private String name;
    private String staatangehoerigkeit;
    private String steuer;
    private Long telefonnumer;
    private String titel;
    private String vorname;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "kiwiantraagsteller", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    private List<Kiwikinder> kiwikinderList;
    public Kiwiantraagsteller() {
        kiwikinderList = new ArrayList<Kiwikinder>();
    }
    public Kiwiantraagsteller(String anschrift, Integer antragstelerid, String bic, String familienstand,
                              String geburtsname, String geschlecht, String iban, String kontoinhaber, String name,
                              String staatangehoerigkeit, String steuer, Long telefonnumer, String titel,
                              String vorname) {
        this.anschrift = anschrift;
        this.antragstelerid = antragstelerid;
        this.bic = bic;
        this.familienstand = familienstand;
        this.geburtsname = geburtsname;
        this.geschlecht = geschlecht;
        this.iban = iban;
        this.kontoinhaber = kontoinhaber;
        this.name = name;
        this.staatangehoerigkeit = staatangehoerigkeit;
        this.steuer = steuer;
        this.telefonnumer = telefonnumer;
        this.titel = titel;
        this.vorname = vorname;
    }
    public String getAnschrift() {
        return anschrift;
    }
    public void setAnschrift(String anschrift) {
        this.anschrift = anschrift;
    }
    public Integer getAntragstelerid() {
        return antragstelerid;
    }
    public String getBic() {
        return bic;
    }
    public void setBic(String bic) {
        this.bic = bic;
    }
    public String getFamilienstand() {
        return familienstand;
    }
    public void setFamilienstand(String familienstand) {
        this.familienstand = familienstand;
    }
    public String getGeburtsname() {
        return geburtsname;
    }
    public void setGeburtsname(String geburtsname) {
        this.geburtsname = geburtsname;
    }
    public String getGeschlecht() {
        return geschlecht;
    }
    public void setGeschlecht(String geschlecht) {
        this.geschlecht = geschlecht;
    }
    public String getIban() {
        return iban;
    }
    public void setIban(String iban) {
        this.iban = iban;
    }
    public String getKontoinhaber() {
        return kontoinhaber;
    }
    public void setKontoinhaber(String kontoinhaber) {
        this.kontoinhaber = kontoinhaber;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getStaatangehoerigkeit() {
        return staatangehoerigkeit;
    }
    public void setStaatangehoerigkeit(String staatangehoerigkeit) {
        this.staatangehoerigkeit = staatangehoerigkeit;
    }
    public String getSteuer() {
        return steuer;
    }
    public void setSteuer(String steuer) {
        this.steuer = steuer;
    }
    public Long getTelefonnumer() {
        try {
        return telefonnumer;}
        catch (Exception ex){ return getTelefonnumer();}
    }
    public void setTelefonnumer(Long telefonnumer) {
        this.telefonnumer = telefonnumer;
    }
    public String getTitel() {
        return titel;
    }
    public void setTitel(String titel) {
        this.titel = titel;
    }
    public String getVorname() {
        return vorname;
    }
    public void setVorname(String vorname) {
        this.vorname = vorname;
    }
    public List<Kiwikinder> getKiwikinderList() {
        return kiwikinderList;
    }
    public void setKiwikinderList(List<Kiwikinder> kiwikinderList) {
        this.kiwikinderList = kiwikinderList;
    }
    public void setAntragstelerid(Integer antragstelerid) {
        this.antragstelerid = antragstelerid;
    }
    public Kiwikinder addKiwikinder(Kiwikinder kiwikinder) {
        getKiwikinderList().add(kiwikinder);
        kiwikinder.setKiwiantraagsteller(this);
        return kiwikinder;
    }
    public Kiwikinder removeKiwikinder(Kiwikinder kiwikinder) {
        getKiwikinderList().remove(kiwikinder);
        kiwikinder.setKiwiantraagsteller(null);
        return kiwikinder;
    }
}**
```

the Test with JUnit:

```
package demo.model;

import org.junit.Assert;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

import sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException;

public class KiwiantraagstellerTest {

    public  KiwiantraagstellerTest() {

    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#getAnschrift()
     */


    @Test
    public void testGetAnschrift() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#setAnschrift(String)
     */
    @Test
    public void testSetAnschrift() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#getAntragstelerid()
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetAntragstelerid() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#getBic()
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetBic() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#setBic(String)
     */
    @Test
    public void testSetBic() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#getFamilienstand()
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetFamilienstand() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#setFamilienstand(String)
     */
    @Test
    public void testSetFamilienstand() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#getGeburtsname()
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetGeburtsname() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#setGeburtsname(String)
     */
    @Test
    public void testSetGeburtsname() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#getGeschlecht()
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetGeschlecht() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#setGeschlecht(String)
     */
    @Test
    public void testSetGeschlecht() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#getIban()
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetIban() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#setIban(String)
     */
    @Test
    public void testSetIban() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#getKontoinhaber()
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetKontoinhaber() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#setKontoinhaber(String)
     */
    @Test
    public void testSetKontoinhaber() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#getName()
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetName() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#setName(String)
     */
    @Test
    public void testSetName() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#getStaatangehoerigkeit()
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetStaatangehoerigkeit() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#setStaatangehoerigkeit(String)
     */
    @Test
    public void testSetStaatangehoerigkeit() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#getSteuer()
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetSteuer() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#setSteuer(String)
     */
    @Test
    public void testSetSteuer() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#getTelefonnumer()
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetTelefonnumer() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#setTelefonnumer(Long)
     */
    @Test
    public void testSetTelefonnumer() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#getTitel()
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetTitel() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#setTitel(String)
     */
    @Test
    public void testSetTitel() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#getVorname()
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetVorname() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#setVorname(String)
     */
    @Test
    public void testSetVorname() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#getKiwikinderList()
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetKiwikinderList() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#setKiwikinderList(java.util.List<demo.model.Kiwikinder>)
     */
    @Test
    public void testSetKiwikinderList() throws Exception {
        Assert.fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#addKiwikinder(Kiwikinder)
     */
    @Test
    public void testAddKiwikinder() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }

    /**
     * @see Kiwiantraagsteller#removeKiwikinder(Kiwikinder)
     */
    @Test
    public void testRemoveKiwikinder() {
        fail("Unimplemented");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tests fail at this line of code:

```
  fail("Unimplemented");
```

Note that this code is in the test driver class, not in the application code.

It is auto-generated code to remind you that you still have to implement these tests.

You need to replace it with the actual test implementation (call some parts of your code under test and assert some results).

In this particular case (many getters and setters that don't seem to have anything "interesting" in them), you probably don't need to test most of these methods. You can delete the test cases that you are not interested in.

Comment: You implement the test. A unit test is supposed to assert that your class does what it is expected to do. For example, by naming convention, your `testGetAnschrift` should assert that your `getAnschrift` method works. However, it looks like you are testing a simple Java bean? Why are you testing this code in the first place? I suggest that you read up on testing code, there are numerous resources available on this topic.